# Navigation bar breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not really sure what is causing my navigation bar to not do its function when it comes to a certain media query, the `icon.png` will open up to show the other options in the menu.

[JSFiddle for my Nav Bar](https://jsfiddle.net/0z8d2dbu/)

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. Maybe you also tell us to which media query it is not working and what exactly is not working?

Comment: @caramba Up to max-width of 780px, the icon will compress the 4 links into a menu, in which can be opened by clicking the icon. It works fine on my dreamweaver, just that it shows a different problem than in the fiddle.

Comment: How should we be able to help if we don't get the error/problem you have got? Please re-read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of course not all of it, just the first 3 bullet points and then you can help us help you. Especially the third point `- Verifiable`